# Convert data audio from microphone to bytes for recognize audio on Google Speech API

Tags: java, audio, google-speech-api

After reading some demo application using Google Speech API. They using file audio for demo.

Example:

```
SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create();
// The path to the audio file to transcribe
String fileName = "./resources/RecordAudio.flac";

// Reads the audio file into memory
Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

// Builds the sync recognize request
RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
 .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC)
 .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
 .setLanguageCode("vi-VI")
 .build();
RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
 .setContent(audioBytes)
 .build();

// Performs speech recognition on the audio file
RecognizeResponse response = speech.recognize(config, audio);
List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();
```

Instead of using audio file, I tried to use Java Sound API for record audio and send it to Google Speech API for recognize. But after recording audio, I get audio data raw in byteOut above.

So I tried convert byteOut

Recording function:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = null;

    //Configure audio format
    AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(16000,16,1,true,true);

    try {
        microphone = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(audioFormat);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,
                audioFormat);
        microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        microphone.open(audioFormat);
        // Start recording
        microphone.start();

        // Create thread for recording
        (new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                stopRecording = false;
                try {
                    while (!stopRecording) {
                        int count = microphone.read(tempBuffer, 0,
                                tempBuffer.length);
                        if (count > 0) {
                            byteOut.write(tempBuffer, 0, count);
                        }
                    }

                    byteOut.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        })).start();
```

After recording, I got data that recorded and save in variable **byteOut**.

For recognize data audio **byteOut**, I tried to write it into RecordAudio.wav, and convert RecordAudio.wav to RecordAudio.flac(I use Audacity for convert them). Finally, Use Google Speech API for recognize RecordAudio.flac file. So I realized that the solution was slow and complicated.

So when read example about Google Speech API above, I think rather than put directly data raw after recording instead of audio file to recognize. Audio raw after recording stored in **byteOut**.

But I really don't know how to convert **byteOut** to **ByteString audioBytes** in Google Speech API example above.

```
ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);
```

Anyone know solution for this. Thank you a lot.

Comment: So, your question comes down to "how do I extract `byte[]` from `ByteArrayOutputStream`", correct?

Comment: Yes, It suitable byte order for Google Speech API.

Comment: I would expect that AudioSystem would produce bytes that are recognizable via Google's `AudioEncoding.LINEAR16`. And `ByteArrayOutputStream` has `byte[] toByteArray()` on it. Although maybe it would be better to stream-recognize instead, to avoid collecting all those bytes in memory (AudioInputStream and such).

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it

Comment: Hello, are you succeed with full sample? Could you please share  your ready solution? I cannot find a good way how to do real-time recording from microphone and converting to text.. Might be you can help me with this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you please share your solution?